# Convert date in UK format and Django format to real date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I am trying to convert `booking.date`, which is in the following format `01/06/2016` to the format `'EEEE, MMMM d, y' (Wednesday, June, 1, 2016)`. I've tried the following AngularJS filter [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) but it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions?

```
<p style="small">{{ booking.date | date:'fullDate' }}<br>{{ booking.time }}</p>
```

I also have another date in the format: `2016-05-31T19:18:24Z` elsewhere, is there another approach I can take for this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the *Date* constructor or *Date.parse* to parse strings (they are equivalent for parsing). Always manually parse strings, a library can help (there are many to chose from) but if you only have one format a simple function is sufficient.

To parse a string in d/m/y format (which is very widely used, it's not peculiar to the UK in the way that m/d/y is to the USA) and validate the values, use a function like:

```js
/* Parse a date string in d/m/y format
** @param {string} s - date string
** @returns {Date} If date is invalid, returns an invalid Date
*/
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = (''+s).split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

document.write(parseDMY('01/05/2016'));
```